# Find longest path in a search binary tree using C

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble finding the code for finding the longest path of a search binary tree using a recursive function.

```
void maxDepth(bst_node *node)
{            ....
}
```

The bst_node is a node of the search binary tree.

The condition of exitting the recursion is very simple:

```
if(node->leftChild==NULL&&node->rightChild==NULL)
{
return;
}
```

Before going to the recursion print the value of the node:

```
printf("%d ",node->value);
```

If lets say a node at depth x has only a left child then the longest path goes through the left child of the node and by using recursion we can write it like this:

```
if(node->rightChld==NULL)
{     
maxDepth(node->leftChild);
}
```

If a node at depth x has only a right child then the longest path goes through the right child of the node and by using recursion we can write it like this

```
if(node->leftChild==NULL)
{
maxDepth(node->rightChild);

}
```

But what if the node has both left and right child?I cannot understand how I can do this.

For example with this binary search tree the output should be:

[image]

"11 13 57 25 17"

Help appreciated.

Comment: Do both, and see which one is better.

Comment: how can I see which one is better?

Comment: The `maxDepth` function needs to report its findings to the caller. That's typically done by returning the depth. In other words, the function is `int maxDepth(bst_node *node)`

Comment: Why is your function a `void` function? What is the supposed effect of calling the function? Can you give example input and corresponding output that the function should give, and how it should give it? (not the return value??)

Comment: @user3386109 i dont get why we have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to carefully think through each possible case. Either it's a base case, or you'll need to decompose it into a smaller problem you can solve with a recursive call.

```
int max(int a, int b) { return a > b ? a : b; }

int maxDepth(bst_node *node)
{
  // If the tree is empty, the depth is zero.
  if (!node) return 0;

  // Otherwise it's this node plus the max of the children.
  return 1 + max(maxDepth(node->leftChild), maxDepth(node->rightChild));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#define max(a, b) a > b ? a : b
```

```c
int maxDepth(bst_node *node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    int max_left = maxDepth(node->leftChild);
    int max_right = maxDepth(node->rightChild);
    return max(max_left, max_right) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Think it through. This always returns zero.